# Error when executing class file in command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

I'm currently in the process of learning more about Java.  I downloaded a sample program that has about 5 different .java files in the source folder.

Whenever I try to execute the class files in the command prompt using "java ClassNameHere", I get a message in the cmd prompt that says **"Error: Could not find or load main class ClassNameHere".**

I've tried recompiling them using the javac command and they compiles without any issues.  Its just the class file i'm having trouble with.

In addition to this, I also cannot run the java files using Eclipse.  Instead of getting an option to "Run as Java Application", "non applicable" appears under the "Run as" tab in Eclipse.

I've tried a number of different solutions already posted online, including another command that uses "java -cp . ClassNameHere" or something along those lines and they have not worked for me.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit
Link to program from my drive since I'm not home

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9_pcTVZTnfEeVdzZmM0ZmFkTmc/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Can you _comment_ with a link to the program you downloaded?

Comment: Link from my drive since I am not home right now https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9_pcTVZTnfEeVdzZmM0ZmFkTmc/edit?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a a procedure that will get the application working in Eclipse. This procedure assumes the following:

- Windows 8. I don't think Linux/Mac OS X procedure would differ greatly, but just in case...

In Eclipse:

1. Right click in Package Explorer, and select `New --> Java Project`.
2. In the New Java Project dialog, uncheck `Use default location`, and click Browse and select the directory you've extracted the zip to, or type the path in the box.
3. Click `Finish`.

From this point, you can run this is a Java Application from Eclipse.

Comment: This allows me to run it as an application, just getting another error now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that at least one of the classes has a main() method.  That would be required for Eclipse to show "Run as Java Application".

Comment: One of the classes does include a main method.

Comment: Is the class in a package?  If so, you would need to run java -cp . package.ClassName

Comment: It is in a package.  I will give that a try when I return home.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

- Run Command Prompt.
- Use `cd C:\path\to\your\porject\java classes`.
- Use `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin` (CHANGE THE PATH TO YOUR jdk1.x.x_xx\bin FOLDER) to tell the system where to find jdk programs.
- Use `javac MainClass.java` to compile the project, MainClass.java si the java class where the main method is.
- Use `java MainClass` (WITHOUT .java EXTENSION) to run the project.

After the last command your project should run correctly.
Sorry for the "use" ripetition but i'm not english.